# How to define a list of optional strings as property of an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to have a property on an interface, `interests` for example, which is a list of one or more pre-defined interests.

For example, the interface would look something like:

```js
// User Data Model
export default interface User {
    uid: String;
    email: string;
    username: string;
    firstName?: String;
    lastName?: String;
    interests: partial<Interests>;
}

// Interests data model
type Interests = ['swimming', 'running', 'movies', 'hiking'];
```

And the implementation could be as follows:

```js
const user: User = {
    uid: "123abc",
    email: "joe@soap.com",
    username: "soapMctavish",
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Soap",
    interests: ["swimming", "movies"]
}
```

The goal is to avoid defining interests as follows:

```js
export default interface User {
    ...
    interests: "Movies" | "Swimming" | "Hiking" | ...etc;
}
```

And to have the ability to define 1 through n interests per user.

Comment: `('swimming' | 'running' | 'movies' | 'hiking')[]`...? Basically `Interests[number][]`

Comment: Thank you :)) That worked for me, if you add it as an answer I will mark as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to somehow get the union

```
'swimming' | 'running' | 'movies' | 'hiking'
```

from

```
type Interests = ['swimming', 'running', 'movies', 'hiking'];
```

You can achieve that by indexing into `Interests` with `number`:

```
Interests[number] // 'swimming' | 'running' | 'movies' | 'hiking'
```

Then you wrap this union into an array for the desired result:

```
Interests[number][] // ('swimming' | 'running' | 'movies' | 'hiking')[]
```